# Getting part of request url inside servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, httprequest, url-pattern

I have an `EmailVerification` Servlet mapped with `/ev/*` url-pattern.

```
http://example.com/ev/ce52320570
```

How can I get this `ce52320570` part of the URL in my Servlet?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                                     throws ServletException, IOException {
      String vid = "";  // Here I need to get the id from the URL
}
```

Comment: If you want *path parameters* you will have to handle them on yourself, basing off `HttpServletRequest` methods. If you could substitute them for *query parameters* everything would be easier.

Comment: I have posted an answer it may be better while it will return the last part only also without containing a slash...

Comment: @acdcjunior I need to take extra care of url's like `http://xyz.com/ev/ce52320570/` - _having an extra `/` in the end_ . it looks a bit of extra work to split and replace stuff. Do you have any better way for this ?

Comment: From `http://xyz.com/ev/ce52320570/`, `request.getPathInfo()` gives you the string `/ce52320570/`. If you want to eliminate the `"/"`s, just call [**`String#replace()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): `String vid = request.getPathInfo().replace("/", "");`. It will give you exactly `ce52320570`. And this is file system independent.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Considering a Servlet (called `EmailVerification`) mapped to `/ev/*`:

> Will the URL **`http://example.com/ev/ce52320570`** trigger the `EmailVerification` servlet ?

Yes. In Servlet versions 2.5 and 3.0 (maybe earlier), it'll get the subpath if you map it with `*`, like `/ev/*`, as you did.

> How can I get this **`ce52320570`** part of the URL **`http://example.com/ev/ce52320570`**?

- [**`request.getRequestURI()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) will get you the requested URL as a `String`, like `/ev/ce52320570`.
- [**`request.getPathInfo()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) gets you (if exists) everything after `/ev/`.

  - So in a request to `/ev/123`, `getPathInfo()` would give you `/123`. The same way, a request to `/ev/some/other`, `getPathInfo()` would give you `/some/other`.
- [**`request.getQueryString()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) should be used if you need the *query parameters* part of the URL.

  - Keep in mind both `getRequestURI()` and `getPathInfo()` give you **only the *path*** requested. If you need to obtain the *query parameters*, that is, those after the `?`, like `/ev/something?query1=value1&other=123`, only `request.getQueryString()` would return the `query1=value1&other=123` part.
- [`request.getParameter(parameterName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) if you need the value of a ***specific*** query **parameter**.

  - Resort to [`.getParameterValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) if it is a multivalued parameter

---

More examples of the URL parts in the request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675399/1850609).

Comment: is their any option other then splitting `/ev/ce52320570` after last `/` to get the id

Comment: Yes, `request.getPathInfo()` gets (if exists) you everything after `/ev/`.

Comment: @acdcjunior In the last part `request.getParameter(paramName)` is more applicable than `requedt.getQueryString()`, as it allows to get the sent value in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.getRequestURI()` and remove what you don't need, i.e. `request.getRequestURI().replace("/ev/");`