# Get full URL and query string in Servlet for both HTTP and HTTPS requests

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I am writing a code which task is to retrieve a requested URL or full path. I've written this code:

```
HttpServletRequest request;//obtained from other functions
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
if (request.getQueryString() != null)
    uri += "?" + request.getQueryString();
```

So, when I browse `http://google.com?q=abc` it is OK (correct).
But there is problem when I browse `https://google.com`. The value of `uri` is `http://google.com:443google.com:443`, So the program doesn't only when `HTTPS` is used.

And the output is same for `request.getRequestURL().toString()`.

What is the solution?

Comment: I think it's most likely that whatever "other functions" that you call to construct the `HttpServletRequest` are constructing it incorrectly. Perhaps you can create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the exact problem?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

By design, [`getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) gives you the full URL, missing only the query string.

In [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), you can get individual parts of the URI using the methods below:

```
// Example: http://myhost:8080/people?lastname=Fox&age=30

String uri = request.getScheme() + "://" +   // "http" + "://
             request.getServerName() +       // "myhost"
             ":" +                           // ":"
             request.getServerPort() +       // "8080"
             request.getRequestURI() +       // "/people"
             "?" +                           // "?"
             request.getQueryString();       // "lastname=Fox&age=30"
```

- `.getScheme()` will give you `"https"` if it was a `https://domain` request.
- `.getServerName()` gives `domain` on `http(s)://domain`.
- `.getServerPort()` will give you the port.

### Use the snippet below:

```
String uri = request.getScheme() + "://" +
             request.getServerName() + 
             ("http".equals(request.getScheme()) && request.getServerPort() == 80 || "https".equals(request.getScheme()) && request.getServerPort() == 443 ? "" : ":" + request.getServerPort() ) +
             request.getRequestURI() +
            (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");
```

This snippet above will get the full URI, hiding the port if the default one was used, and not adding the `"?"` and the query string if the latter was not provided.

### Proxied requests

Note, that if your request passes through a proxy, you need to look at the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header since the scheme might be altered:

```
request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto")
```

Also, a common header is `X-Forwarded-For`, which show the original request IP instead of the proxys IP.

```
request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
```

If you are responsible for the configuration of the proxy/load balancer yourself, you need to ensure that these headers are set upon forwarding.

Comment: Your first code helped with repetition in  `https` but with error. There is no query string in `https`

Comment: already corrected and same error. and yes i've tried getRequestURL()

Comment: @ErBnAcharya `getRequestURL()` **must work**. Seems like you're doing something wrong...

Comment: Using the expression in the answer, what's the value of `uri`?

Comment: @acdcjunior As an additional variant: you can use [`getHeader("Host")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)) to get **both** the host and the port.

Comment: @ErBnAcharya It's very strange that you get `google.com:443` **twice**. Plus I see there *http* instead of **https**...

Comment: I second @informatik01 on the strangeness of this. Here's something you can do: print piece by piece, each on a separate line (`getScheme()` in one `getServerName()` in other), what's the result? This will give you a hint about what's the problematic part.

Comment: I think error is on `request.getQueryString()` which is returning `null` for `https://google.com?q=a`

Comment: Everyone else is bringing the expected result? Who's building that `HttpServletRequest` you're getting as parameter? Whoever does that, is doing it wrong.

Comment: I am invoking my class as jetty handle. So object is obtained using jetty.

Comment: Hi! I know its been a long time, but have you managed to get this working?

Comment: Does is exist a way to get URI fragment also?

Comment: @agad Unfortunately, no. As `request` is a server-side object, it cannot get URI fragments as those are never sent to the server by the browsers.

Comment: I think the example is missing context path

Comment: Ain't `/people` the context path?

Answer (score 10):

### Simply Use:

```
String Uri = request.getRequestURL()+"?"+request.getQueryString();
```

Comment: Note that `getRequestURL` will not work on an error page. So if you have a `404.jsp` and e.g. need to do a redirect you will need add import: `<%@ page import="org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil" %>` and use `String requestedLocation = RequestUtil.filter((String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri"));`

Answer (score 4):

The fact that a `HTTPS` request becomes `HTTP` when you tried to construct the URL on server side indicates that you might have a proxy/load balancer (`nginx`, `pound`, etc.) offloading SSL encryption in front and forward to your back end service in plain `HTTP`.

If that's case, check,

1. whether your proxy has been set up to forward headers correctly (`Host`, `X-forwarded-proto`, `X-forwarded-for`, etc).
2. whether your service container (E.g. `Tomcat`) is set up to recognize the proxy in front. For example, `Tomcat` requires adding `secure="true" scheme="https" proxyPort="443"` attributes to its `Connector`
3. whether your code, or service container is processing the headers correctly. For example, `Tomcat` automatically replaces `scheme`, `remoteAddr`, etc. values when you add `RemoteIpValve` to its `Engine`. (see [Configuration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Valve), [JavaDoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)) so  you don't have to process these headers in your code manually.

Incorrect proxy header values could result in incorrect output when `request.getRequestURI()` or `request.getRequestURL()` attempts to construct the originating URL.

Comment: This was the solution of the problem. Extending this, [read the server.xml Connector docs!](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a Java question, but if you're using Kotlin you can do this quite nicely:

```kotlin
val uri = request.run {
    if (queryString.isNullOrBlank()) requestURI else "$requestURI?$queryString"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring users, [`ServletUriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.22/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html) handles this.

```java
// autowire HttpServletRequest to use here
String fullURL = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequest(request).build().toString();
// or use current request
String fullURL = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().build().toString();
```