# How to get the full requested URL in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a URL like

```
www.abc.com/;jsessionid=53AA662D24A89922031913A6E85A005B
```

(sorry i can't specify my actual site name here, so using `abc.com`)

When the above url is hit, i want to strip `;jsessionid=53AA662D24A89922031913A6E85A005B` from the above url in the back-end (in my servlet) and redirect to the actual url (in this example  `http://www.abc.com/`).

I have tried many ways in my servlet to know whether the requested URL has 'jsessionid' or not, but I can't find a method that returns the full requested URL on HTTP request object

I have tried the following methods on the HTTP request object

- `getRequestURI()`
- `getRequestURL()`
- `getContextPath()`
- `getPathInfo()`

but they are not returning the full requested url with the `jsessionid`.

I have tried `getParameter()`, `getParameterNames()` but no help as the above url doesn't have `?` before `jsessionid`.

Comment: when specifying an 'example' site name like that, the standard practice is to use `example.com` rather than `abc.com` (the actual domain example.com is reserved for this use, whereas abc.com points to a real site, which obviously isn't yours)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675191/get-full-url-and-query-string-in-servlet-for-both-http-and-https-requests/16675399

Comment: If none of those methods returns `;jsessionid=...` it has already been removed by the servlet container, whose job it is to manage the session. *Ergo* you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 8):

here is how you can  retrieve the complete url above in your Servlet

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                       throws IOException, ServletException {

               String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
              System.out.println(url);
               }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have tried but didn't work. here i have taken the example: https://www.google.com/;jsessionid=53AA662D24A89922031913A6E85A005B in this link i want to retrieve the jsessionid value in my servlet. As the "?" is not there before the jsessionid i am not able to retrieve it. Can you please kindly help me how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    String jSessionId=request.getParameter("jsessionid");

    System.out.println("jSessionId:"+jSessionId);    
}
```