# how to get URL from address bar in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Lets say I hit

> `http://localhost/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marksandspencer/l/women/dresses/party-and-cocktail-dresses`

and this internally redirects me to custom 404.jsp page, But URL remain same in address bar.

I tried this code - `<%= request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri") %>;` and it's returning me the path of 404.jsp

How can I get the entered URL which is there in address bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get full URL and query string in Servlet for both HTTP and HTTPS requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675191/get-full-url-and-query-string-in-servlet-for-both-http-and-https-requests)

Comment: No, it's not duplicate of above question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were close. `javax.servlet.forward.request_uri` is for normal forwarding, but for 404, you need `javax.servlet.error.request_uri`.

Comment: From Tomcat 10 onwards it's jakarta.servlet.forward.request_uri

Answer (score 4):

Use **request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")** to get URI of requested page that not found (404 error). Check this: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/constant-values.html

When error raised (because of some reason such as page not found (404), Internal Server Error (500), ...), the servlet engine will FORWARD the request to corresponding error page (configured in web.xml) using **ERROR dispatcher type**, **NOT FORWARD dispatcher type** so that is the reason we must **use javax.servlet.error.request_uri, NOT use javax.servlet.forward.request_uri**

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

but this doesn't hold Query String. So, to get query string, you may call

```
request.getQueryString()
```

Comment: As you can see my URL is SEO  URL and request.getRequestURL() will return us the JSP mapped to this seo but what i want is SEO url in my JSP.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what is *SEO URL*.. :p

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the whole URL including parameters.

```
    request.getRequestURL()+""+request.getQueryString();
```

Answer (score -2):

use `request.getHeader("Referer")`.

referer gives a url from where you redirected.

Comment: it's giving me null :(

Comment: yes! page is redirected to 404.jsp when application doesn't find entered URL.