# Updating html checkbox base on URL params without using JavaScript (Java with XSL/XML)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, url

I'm working on a project (Java with XSL/XML) where I have to make the least changes to the already existing code, but I have this scenario and I want to know if it is possible.
Let's say I have this form :

```
<form method="get">
            <input id="checkbox-has-file" type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox" value="test">
            <input name="" type="submit" value="sup">
</form>
```

Is it possible to like pre-select the checkbox using only the url parameters, like this :

```
localhost/page.html?myCheckBox=true
```

I know it is possible using JavaScript or JQuery, but I'm trying to avoid extra code.

Thank you!

Comment: So, uh, you want to do something without changing anything? Kinda self-condradictory. If you don't want to use JavaScript you could do it on the server side.

Comment: which backend language do you use in this example?

Comment: @hsnbl It's Java with XSL/XML templates.

Comment: @BjörnTantau Where do you get the anything? That's not what I said. I said with the least changes possible, I'm already doing something with the query parameters and It would be better if I don't change/add something else.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675399/8175473

Comment: @hsnbl Thank you!

Comment: @M.Hamidi your welcome

Answer (score 1):

Without any programming language (JavaScript etc.) it isn't possible.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to confirm, do you have any sources?

Answer (score 1):

Use [PHP](http://www.php.net/):

Here is a sample php file:

```
<form method="get">
        <input id="checkbox-has-file" type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox" value="test" checked="<?php echo $_GET['myCheckBox'];?>">
        <input name="" type="submit" value="sup">
```

Comment: The software I'm using is written in Java and the page are in XSL/XML, I'm not allowed to use PHP, Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Oh I see, it looks like you can't do it with those requirements ;)

Comment: Seems like it :(