# HttpServlet: Url that contains ID between resources

Tags: java, url, servlets, url-pattern

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501478/getting-part-of-request-url-inside-servlet)

but it does not help my case.

I have a class that implements an HttpServlet. Now I want to place a URL inside it so that it has the following pattern: resource/identifier/resource.

For example, I want to make this REST call: http://example.com/owners/1234/dogs

I tried to place a URL like this in the servlet: http://example.com/owners/*/dogs, but the call never reached the servlet and was not handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well you want your servlet to be mapped to something like  `/owners/*/dogs`.

Well, unfortunately Servlets can only use wildcards at the beginning or end of the mapping. So you would have to map it to `/owners/*` and then using `request.getPathInfo()` parse the rest of the url to extract the path info.

Your best options are to use the standard JAXRS or Spring MVC, both of which support path variables.